# How to insert timestamp into rails database-column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started with RoR and have a question: How can I insert the current timestamp (or any type of time) into the model? Below you see the log function create.

```
def create
    @log = Log.new(params[:log])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @log.save
        format.html { redirect_to @log, notice: 'Log was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @log, status: :created, location: @log }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @log.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Did you create the model using the rails generator?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Rails model generator automatically creates  `created_at` and `updated_at` `datetime` fields in the database for you. These fields are automatically updated when a record is created or updated respectively.

If you want to manually create a timestamp, add a datetime column (e.g. `timestamp_field`) to the database and use a `before_save` callback in your model.

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :generate_timestamp

  def generate_timestamp
    self.timestamp_field = DateTime.now
  end
end
```

Comment: But I would insert the timestamp.

Comment: Don't you need to write `self.timestamp_field = DateTime.now`?

Comment: @DonKirkby I believe so, as `timestamp_field`  is currently defined as a local variable and as far as I know, ActiveRecord doesn't assume anything about variable names matching class attributes. So, one would need to preface with `self` as you have suggested, or make it an instance variable by prefacing with `@`. Then again, I've never encountered this scenario, just speculating.

Answer (score 5):

Using the rails generator e.g `rails generate model Log` rails creates two timestamp fields automatically for you.

`created_at` and `updated_at` both of these fields will be filled by Rails when you create a new record doing `Log.new` then `save` on that record or `Log.create` The `updated_at` field gets updated only when you update the record's attributes or when you use the method `touch` on an instance of the model.

Now, if you wanted to create another field with the timestamp type you could make a migration that adds a column to your model like this

```
rails generate migration add_some_timestamp_field_to_logs my_timestamp_field:timestamp
```

This will generate a migration that will add a column named `my_timestamp_field` with a `timestamp` type, just like the `created_at` and `updated_at`