# Rails created_at not being set for new records on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, timestamp

Rails 4.2.1

I just added a new table to my db for messages, and for some reason the normal created_at and updated_at timestamps that are generated by a rails migration by default weren't added, so I was unable to access them with @message.created_at. I added them myself with a new migration, which worked in development on my local machine, but when I pushed in heroku and migrated the db on heroku, the created_at and updated_at fields are being set to nil when a new message is created.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you look in your CreateMessage (or whatever you called it) migration file, do you see a line like 't.timestamps null: false'?

Comment: no, here's the migration class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :subject
      t.text :body
    end
  end
end

Comment: and then here's the other migration to add timestamps to messages, which like i said works in development class AddTimestampsToMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column(:messages, :created_at, :datetime)
    add_column(:messages, :updated_at, :datetime)
  end
end

Comment: So i just had to work around this by adding my own custom datetime field as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15422740/2511012

Answer (score 1):

[Rails creating records with timestamps set to nil, 'heroku restart' solves it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463317/rails-creating-records-with-timestamps-set-to-nil-heroku-restart-solves-it) helped me out. I had a new migration that added a timestamp column. I ran db:migrate on heroku but kept getting an error. A `heroku restart -a app_name` fixed it for me.